# Add script tag to magento layout.xml

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm currently developing a eCommerce system with Magento. I have my footer called as
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>`
and my layout.xml has following tags to define the 'footer'

```
<reference name="footer">
  <block type="page/footer" name="footer">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/html/footer_home.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>muaw/footer_script.phtml</template>
    </action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

`footer_home.phtml` is the actual footer and `footer_script.phtml` is a file with `<script>` tag for some jquery. My problem is that adding the second set of `<action>` tags for `footer_script.phtml` replace the actual footer. Is there any other way to get both files?

Comment: Since footer will always show in site, and u have script in <script> tag right, it means its js file, no php code right? so, just add <action method="addJs">
    <script>js/custom-script.js</script>
</action> and put that js in js folder.

Comment: good idea. but i don't think that is the best practice. thanx anyway.

Comment: You're calling two times the `setTemplate()` method on the `page/footer` block. This does not make any sense because that block can only have one template, not two. Calling the method twice with a different tamplate parameter therefore renders one of them useless. Therefore it's obvious for whatever what you've tried to do, you've used the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set two templates for the footer. Just refrence your phtml file like so...

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="page/footer" name="footer">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/html/footer_home.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="core/template" name="footer_script" template="muaw/footer_script.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add footer_script.phtml to

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
```